# tables in pine script not showing

Tags: pine-script

I have 6 tables, 3 of them display on daily timeframe and 3 of them on weekly. I will add the full code at the end.

Each of those 3 tables position is top_center, middle_left and bottom_center

For simplicity on this explanation, this is the structure:

```
3 First tables declaration (let's call them A, B and C)
3 Second tables declaration

if barstate.islast
   if daily timeframe: calling table.cell for each daily table
   if weekly timeframe: calling table.cell for each weekly table
```

The result I get is that the tables A and C are always hidden (whichever they are, if I declare the second tables before the first, the tables declared in position A and C are hidden, meaning the weekly A and C hidden and all the daily ones display fine and the other way around)

Image of result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgHVF.png)

Full code below (I just removed repetitive row creation, since the problem stays the same even with less amount of rows)

```
//TABLE CREATION
f_fillCell(_table, _column, _row, _text) =>
    _cellText = _text
    table.cell(_table, _column, _row, _cellText, bgcolor = background_color, text_color = text_color, text_halign = text.align_left, text_valign = text.align_top, text_size = size.small , width = 0)

//DAILY TABLES
    //Top Center Table
tc_d_table_columns = 1
tc_d_table_rows = 2
var table tc_d_table = table.new(position.top_center, tc_d_table_columns, tc_d_table_rows, border_width = 3)
    //Top Left Table
tl_d_table_columns = 4
tl_d_table_rows = 11
var table tl_d_table = table.new(position.middle_left, tl_d_table_columns, tl_d_table_rows, border_width = 3)
    //Bottom Center Table
bc_d_table_columns = 9
bc_d_table_rows = 4
var table bc_d_table = table.new(position.bottom_center, bc_d_table_columns, bc_d_table_rows, border_width = 3)

//WEEKLY TABLES
    //Top Center Table
tc_w_table_columns = 3
tc_w_table_rows = 4
var table tc_w_table = table.new(position.top_center, tc_w_table_columns, tc_w_table_rows, border_width = 3)
    //Top Left Table
tl_w_table_columns = 4
tl_w_table_rows = 11
var table tl_w_table = table.new(position.middle_left, tl_w_table_columns, tl_w_table_rows, border_width = 3)
    //Bottom Center Table
bc_w_table_columns = 5
bc_w_table_rows = 5
var table bc_w_table = table.new(position.bottom_center, bc_w_table_columns, bc_w_table_rows, border_width = 3)

show_daily_tables = false
show_weekly_tables= false 
if timeframe.isdaily
    show_daily_tables := true
    show_weekly_tables := false
else if timeframe.isweekly
    show_daily_tables := false
    show_weekly_tables := true

if barstate.islast
    if show_daily_tables
    //Top Center Table
        f_fillCell(tc_d_table, 0, 0, "DAILY TABLES")
        f_fillCell(tc_d_table, 0, 1, " ")
    //Top Left Table
        f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 0, 0, " "), f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 1, 0, " "),   f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 2, 0, " ")
        f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 0, 1, " "), f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 1, 1, " "),   f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 2, 1, " "),      f_fillCell(tl_d_table, 3, 1, " ")
        
    //Bottom Center Table
        f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 0, 0, " "), f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 1, 0, " "),   f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 2, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 3, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 4, 0, " ")
        f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 0, 1, " "), f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 1, 1, " "),   f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 2, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 3, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_d_table, 4, 1, " ")
    else if show_weekly_tables
    //Top Center Table
        f_fillCell(tc_w_table, 0, 0, "WEEKLY TABLES")
        f_fillCell(tc_w_table, 0, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(tc_w_table, 1, 1, " ")

    //Top Left Table
        f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 0, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 1, 0, " "),      f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 2, 0, " ")
        f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 0, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 1, 1, " "),      f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 2, 1, " "),      f_fillCell(tl_w_table, 3, 1, " ")

    //Bottom Center Table
        f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 0, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 1, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 2, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 3, 0, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 4, 0, " ")
        f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 0, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 1, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 2, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 3, 1, " "),  f_fillCell(bc_w_table, 4, 1, " ")
```

Comment: You create tables once (because `var`). Try to remove `var` table declaration: `var table tc_d_table = table.new(...` --> `tc_d_table = table.new(...`

Comment: Thank you Andrey, whether your answer worked on not, you are the Boss:) I am a big fan of your answers for some time. about my issue, I can't tell how I fixed it, I just removed and recreated the problematic tables. And having Var or removing as you said also works well.

Comment: I have one more question related to that one: I am creating a new table on the same position (position.middle_left) and with different columns and same rows. And now my other 2 tables that are there, disappear.  `table tl_w_table_new = table.new(position.middle_left, 1, tl_w_table_rows, border_width = 3)`

Comment: Now it makes sense, when tables are on the same position with different amount of columns or rows it seems to keep the one with lesser rows or columns. that is the reason I could fix the problem by recreating the full table since I copied the table that was working and kept same columns and rows

Comment: If new table are created on the some position all tables on this position that have been created before will be deleted implicitly.